# leaflet failed focus on map to marker coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have coordinates table.

I want to this scenario.

> 1 if I clicked td(2nd-child) (When I click on the coordinates row)
>
> 2 alert!
>
> 3 I would like the map's focus to be moved to the marker with that coordinate.

```
var southWest = L.latLng(l, r);
var northEast = L.latLng(l+0.062, r+0.102);

console.log("southWest : ", southWest);
console.log("northEast : ", northEast);
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

map.setView(bounds, 11, { animation: true });
```

this is not working. maps turns out grey.

```
function centerLeafletMapOnMarker(map, latLngs) {
        console.log("좌표: ", latLngs);
        console.log("좌표 길이 : ", latLngs.length);

        if (latLngs.length == 1) {
            // 폴리곤의 좌표
        } else if (latLngs.length == 2) {
            // 마커의 좌표
            console.log("마커의 좌표 : ", latLngs);
            // map.setView(latLngs, 2); bounds로 해야하나보네 ㅠ
            var  [l, r] = latLngs;
            console.log("left : ", l);
            console.log("right: ", r);
            var southWest = L.latLng(l, r);
            var northEast = L.latLng(l+0.062, r+0.102);
            console.log("southWest : ", southWest);
            console.log("northEast : ", northEast);
            var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            // map.setView(bounds, 11, { animation: true });

            map.flyTo([l, r], 13);

            // map.fitBounds(bounds);
            // map.fitBounds([
            //     [l, r],
            //     [l+0.062, r-0.102]
            // ]);
            // https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#latlngbounds
        } else {

        }
        // var corner1 = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
        //     corner2 = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125),
        //     bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2);
        // map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

here is live code

> output > https://output.jsbin.com/bojituv
>
> code > https://jsbin.com/bojituv/edit?html,output

The map doesn't focus where I want it.

I only see the gray screen and the sea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you have your latitude and longitude reversed. Secondly, I'm not entirely sure what your `if (($this)).index()` line is supposed to be doing. My assumption is that you want to check to see if `coordinates` exist in the string.

So, I made these changes:

- Changed `if ($(this).index())` line to `if($(this).text().includes("coordinates"))`.
- Reversed your lat/lon in your `centerLeafletMapOnMarker` function.

Updated JSBin: https://jsbin.com/yobapipowi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

Both `setView` and `flyTo` take a single `LatLng` and center the map on that position, whereas the `fitBounds` and `flyToBounds` function take a `LatLngBounds` object and fits the bounds of the map to those bounds.

So instead of calling `flyTo` and `setView`, you should use `flyToBounds` and `fitBounds` respectively instead:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var marker = L.marker([40.416038, -3.703583]).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function flyToBounds() {
  // This moves the map to the supplied bounds
  var bounds = [
    [36.084514, -9.703365],
    [42.220937, 5.078856]
  ];
  
  map.flyToBounds(bounds);
}

function setView() {
  // This moves the map to a single LatLng
  var pos = marker.getLatLng();
  map.setView([pos.lat, pos.lng]);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<button onclick="flyToBounds()">Fly To Bounds</button>
<button onclick="setView()">Set View</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

Comment: No need to break out the lat and lng in setView(): you can just do map.setView(marker.getLatLng());